# mysql++ problem with linking

Tags: visual-c++, mysql++

I have problem, I use mysql++ 3.1.0:
after building mysql++.sln in debug and release mode for vc2008, and using instal.hta then
adding dirrectoires in vc++ directories to lib and include folders,
and adding in project properties-> Linker-> General Additional Library Directories directory to lib folder which have mysqlpp.dll, mydqlpp.lib, mysqlpp_d.dll, mydqlpp_d.lib.
These code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql++.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace mysqlpp;

int main()
{
    Connection con;

    return 0;
}
```

gets these errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall mysqlpp::Connection::~Connection(void)" (__imp_??1Connection@mysqlpp@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall mysqlpp::Connection::Connection(bool)" (__imp_??0Connection@mysqlpp@@QAE@_N@Z) referenced in function _main
```

in visual studio 2008. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the last step [here](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/incorporating.html#inc-vstudio), which adds several libraries to your project: the MySQL++ DLL import library, the MySQL C API library, and the Winsock DLL import library.

Comment: Excuse me, my English isn't very good, so I don't understand you well.If you are speaking about adding mysql server libraries to my project  I did it. Or I must add something else to my project?

Comment: That's just one of the three you need. You need `libmysql.lib`, `wsock32.lib`, *and* `mysqlpp.lib`. You have probably left out the last one at least.

Comment: Yes, you do. It's part of the Windows SDK, which comes with Visual C++. Just add it to the library list.